# Why is my backbone view render putting "undefined" at the top?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Most of the render function in the following view is irrelevant, I think but I'm leaving it for completeness. I'm stepping through a list of workflow steps, noting switching the class of the `li` depending on various states of the thing.

```
var WorkStepView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "workflowStep",

    render: function() {
        var output;
        var arrowPlaced = false;
        var self = this;
        i = 0;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(s) {
            var post = "";
            var classname = '';
            if (s.attributes["complete"] != 1) {
                if (! arrowPlaced) {
                    classname = "current";
                    if (s.attributes["adminCompletable"] == 1 ) {
                        post = ' - <input onClick="completeStep(' + i + ');" type="button" value="Completed" />';
                    }
                    arrowPlaced = true;
                }
                else {
                    classname = "future";
                }
            }
            else {
                classname = "past";
            }
            output += '<li class="' + classname + '">' +  s.attributes["description"] + post + '</li>';
            i++;
        });
        this.el.innerHTML = output;
        return this;
    },
});
```

When the user selects an asset from a list elsewhere on the page, it brings up a bunch of data including this stuff. An asset "has" a workflow, which "has" many steps. The step data is stored in window.Steps, and then this is called:

```
function populateSteps() {
    window.workStepLists = new WorkStepView({
        collection: window.Steps,
        el: $('#workflowSteps')[0],
    });
    workStepLists.render();
}
```

But then I get this:
[image]

There's this extraneous "undefined" up there at the top of the list. It wasn't there before fetching and rendering this model. I don't know what's up with that at all.

Help?

Comment: Just a note: You should be doing `s.get("propName")` instead of `s.attributes["propName"]`.  I don't expect that to be a problem, but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Also, a preferred way to use the Underscore `each` function is `this.collection.each(function(){});` but that is really just picking nits.

Comment: If you do a `console.log(output)` after the loop, what does it look like?

Comment: @BrianGenisio - Thanks for all the pointers. I'm just getting started with Backbone, I can see I'm not doing things The Backbone Way. `output` comes to the console with "undefined" at the beginning of it. I changed its declaration to `var output = ''`, and ta da! no more "undefined". Go ahead and put that in as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing `output` to be anything.  So, `output += "foo"` becomes "undefinedfoo".

Simply initialize your output variable with an empty string:

```
var output = '';
```

Comment: I love JavaScript. What other language can coerce the nothingness of undefinedness to the literal string "undefined"? Thanks Brian.